# Spring AOP and Exception Intercepting

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I'm trying to configure Spring so that it executes advice when a specific exception subclass (`MyTestException`) is thrown:

```
public class MyTestExceptionInterceptor implements ThrowsAdvice {
    public void afterThrowing(Method method, Object[] args, Object target, Exception exc) {
        // I want this to get executed every time a MyTestException is thrown,
        // regardless of the package/class/method that is throwing it.
    }
}
```

And the XML config:

```
<bean name="interceptor" class="org.me.myproject.MyTestExceptionInterceptor"/>

<aop:config>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="interceptor" pointcut="execution(???)"/>
</aop:config>
```

I have a feeling that I should be using the `target` pointcut specifier (instead of `execution`) since - according to the [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html) - it seems as though `target` allows me to specify the type of exception to match against, but I'm not sure if that's wrong, or what my `pointcut` attribute needs to look like.

I would **greatly** prefer to keep the AOP config done in XML (as opposed to Java/annotations, but I could probably translate an annotation-based solution into XML if need be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use an [`<aop:after-throwing>` element](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-schema-advice-after-throwing) and its `throwing` attribute.

**Spring config**

```
<bean name="tc" class="foo.bar.ThrowingClass"/>

<bean name="logex" class="foo.bar.LogException"/>

<aop:config>
  <aop:aspect id="afterThrowingExample" ref="logex">
    <aop:after-throwing method="logIt" throwing="ex"
                        pointcut="execution(* foo.bar.*.foo(..))"/>
  </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

The `throwing` attribute is the parameter name of the aspect's handler method (here it's `LogException.logIt`) that gets called on the exception:

**Aspect**

```
public class LogException {
    public void logIt(AnException ex) {
        System.out.println("*** " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The XML and method combo defines the exception type that the aspect applies to. In this example, `ThrowingClass` throws `AnException` and `AnotherException`. Only `AnException` will have the advice applied because of the advice's method signature.

[See example project on github for full source](https://github.com/davelnewton/spring-after-throwing-example).

Answer (score 1):

Check out a AfterThrowingAdvice. An example is found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-examples-advice/) (search for "After throwing advice") and you'll find it.